# how to merge only my forked personal repository

Tags: git, github

I made a fork and cloned it from my personal repository. Then, I checked it remotely using this command:

```
Git remote -v
```

Then I can see the fetch and the push, point to my personal repository like this:

```
Origin github/myPersonalrepo/myForkedRepo.git (fetch)
Origin github/myPersonalrepo/myForkedRepo.git (push)
```

everything works up to this point, but when I do a `git push --all origin` the pull request appears in the Original repo but not in my personal repository.
How can I merge in my personal repository only? and the Original leave it intact. is this possible?

Comment: Not enough info. What did you actually do locally? Did you create a branch? Did you set its upstream?

Comment: hi matt is correct, after i clone the repo i made my branch (git checkout -b localBranch), also established my upstream like:   git remote add upstream <url of Original repo.git> the changes i made in my branch (localBranch) then i check status git status add my changes git add . after git checkout master then git pull origin master, git checkout localBranch and git push --all origin but pull request appears in original Repo

Comment: Instead of `git push --all origin` say `git push -u origin localBranch`

Comment: hi matt i tried, this `git push -u origin localBranch` the green button for compare & pull request appears in my personal repo but when i click it redirects me to Original repo and i think is here (Original Repo) where the merge will take place, is correct? but i just want leave intact the Original repo while in my personal repo do the merge.

Comment: “but when i click it redirects me to Original repo” No, I don’t think it does that. Maybe you don’t understand the interface? Look carefully at the branches you are comparing. Make sure this is localBranch vs this master, not the upstream master.

Comment: i said redirects me to Original repo, beacuse in the top left-hand corner appear the name of the Original repo and mine does not appear. Then i think i am in the original repo and not in mine. And yes i only compare localBranch with master they both of origin (personal repo)